# django-social-auth on google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-socialauth

I'm having trouble getting django-social-auth to work with a Django app that I'm deploying on Google's App Engine using the djangoappengine and django-nonrel.

I'm a noob at this and its quite complex for me ! 
I started with the [django-nonrel template](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) using this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoJA473P3jU) and though I get the login page, it always gives me the error - `Incorrect authentication service`. 
If I do not define the Consumer Key and Secret for Google-oauth2, then I get an `invalid client` error on Google's page.

When I run test social_auth, I am getting FAILED(errors=9) with the issue `Ensure that the backend for the testcase gets cached.` and 
`self.assertTrue(self.user)`
`AssertionError: None is not true for all the errors`.

Could someone please tell direct me to what I should do next to get this to work? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just fell into this problem and think that even if you have already solved this problem, it would be helpful for others if an answer exists.

Go to [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) homepage and download the latest version.
Extract the archive and move the inner httplib2 folder (found inside python2 sub-folder), in your projects main folder.
Then finally add 'httplib2', in your INSTALLED_APPS section, on top of the social_auth's dependencies.

For example here is my INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',
    'httplib2',#    These 4 are
    'openid',#      what u need to
    'oauth2',#      integrate social_auth plug
    'social_auth',# in your GAE project
    'myapp',
    'djangoappengine',
)
```

Note: you also have to place in your projects folder: openid, oauth2 and social_auth, because there is no way afaik you can install them on GAE.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer Thodoris,

Just for completion:

- [OAuth2](http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2)
- [OpenID](http://github.com/openid/python-openid)